# Checking whether a string contains a substring only once

Tags: java, strings

I want to check if a string contains only a *single* occurrence of the given substring (so the result of `containsOnce("foo-and-boo", "oo")` should be `false`). In *Java*, a simple and straightforward implementation would be either

```
boolean containsOnce(final String s, final CharSequence substring) {
    final String substring0 = substring.toString();
    final int i = s.indexOf(substring0);
    return i != -1 && i == s.lastIndexOf(substring0);
}
```

or

```
boolean containsOnce(final String s, final CharSequence substring) {
        final String substring0 = substring.toString();
        final int i = s.indexOf(substring0);
        if (i == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        final int nextIndexOf = s.indexOf(substring0, i + 1);
        return nextIndexOf == 0 || nextIndexOf == -1; // nextIndexOf is 0 if both arguments are empty strings.
}
```

Can you suggest a simpler/more efficient implementation?

Comment: Why do you assume the solution is not efficient? In your first solution you only scan the characters that are needed, which seems very efficient already?

Comment: @RobAu In the first implementation you scan the string up till the end to search for a second occurence. If you search for `oo` in the string `ooaooxxxxxxxxxxxxx....(huge string here)` the second solution will only scan 2 + 3 letters. The first will scan the full huge string. I do agree that the second solution is efficient and readable enough though.

Comment: @Imus maybe I am missing something, but if the huge string is `ooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoo` the first solution will be faster as `lastIndexOf()` scans backwards?

Comment: Aha, you are correct. ignore my previous comment :). Then it also comes down to preference on which is more readable, the first solution or my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using pattern matching. It looks more readable to me, but I have no idea about which is more efficient.

```
public static boolean containsOnce(final String s, final CharSequence substring) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(substring.toString());
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if(matcher.find()){
        return !matcher.find();
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(containsOnce("aba","a"));    //false
    System.out.println(containsOnce("abab", "ab")); //false
    System.out.println(containsOnce("aba", "b"));   //true
    System.out.println(containsOnce("aaa", "aa"));  //true
    System.out.println(containsOnce("",""));        //true
    System.out.println(containsOnce("ab",""));      //false
}
```

Also note that `containsOnce("aaa","aa")` returns `true`. Not sure if you would count this as correct or not.

Note: you can also write it as

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(substring.toString());
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
return matcher.find() && !matcher.find();
```

I don't know which of the two is more readable.

EDIT:

After looking up whichever is faster: indexof vs matcher
It seems to be the general consensus that indexof is a bit faster, but that we're talking about such low times that it really doesn't matter much.

Go for whichever solution you prefer I guess ...

Comment: `containsOnce("ab", "*")` throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the original post. It's concise and readable:

```
boolean containsOnce(String s, String sub) {
  int firstIndex = s.indexOf(sub)
  return firstIndex >=0 && firstIndex == s.lastIndexOf(sub)
}
```

I was writing a test recently that needed to verify that adding a string would refuse if it was already present (I used a set in the black box method) so I wrote something like this:

```
public void testNonDuplicateAdd() {
  String actual = methodUnderTest(stringToAdd, addingTo);
  assertThat(actual, containsString(stringToAdd));
  int firstIndex = actual.indexOf(stringToAdd);
  int lastIndex = actual.lastIndexOf(stringToAdd);
  assertThat(firstIndex, equals(lastIndex));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In terms of efficiency, the `substring.toString()` is the showstopper as soon as `substring` is not a `java.lang.String`. The rest of the code looks fine.

The documentation of the method should include `containsOnce("fooo", "oo")` as an example for returning `false`, since that might be a non-obvious corner case.